# How to get the value of a checkbox in JavaScript?

Tags: angularjs

Please excuse this potentially rather simple question but I have to make a small change to a client Request and don't really have an idea of AngularJS.

In [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) the value of a check box gets requested using these `{{ .. }}` directives inside the HTML code - but how can I access it in JavaScript?

This is the checkbox I try to get its value from:

```
<input ng-switch-when="java.lang.Boolean" type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="nounTypesOnly" required                            
       ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"></input>
```

In the `filter()` method I try to access the value like this:

```
$scope.filter = function(topicIndex) {

    // Already tried: 
    //     $scope.$digest() 

    // $scope.nounTypesOnly is undefined at this point!
    $scope.filterRequest.nounTypesOnly = $scope.nounTypesOnly;
    $scope.doFilter();
};
```

If I debug this `$scope.nounTypesOnly` is undefined. What do I have to change in order to get that value from the input field `nounTypesOnly`?

Comment: did you tried to `$scope.$digest()` and then see the value of `nounTypesOnly`

Comment: @AvraamMavridis Just tested it but it did not work :/

Comment: I think in case of checkbox you have to use `ng-change`

Comment: @AvraamMavridis The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) says it is optional. I'm not sure if this kick in if the user e.g. never click on the item but I can try it.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you initialize `$scope.nounTypesOnly`?

Comment: @Daniel Well, not that I know. How would I initialize it?

Comment: Nevermind, i guess my comment was irrelevant, according to the answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running in a problem with **scope inheritance**.

`<ng-switch-when>` will spawn a new scope. Because of that `ng-model="nounTypesOnly"` binds to this isolated scope not the outer one.

Try to assign the model value to a complex object, i.e. `ng-model="foo.nounTypesOnly"`. This ensures it is accessible in the outer scope via the given name if you initialized `foo = {}` on the outer scope.

#### Example

In your controller, do something like:

```
function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.data = {};
}
```

In your template, do something like:

```
<input ng-switch-when="java.lang.Boolean" ng-model="data.nounTypesOnly" />
```

This way you make sure the `nounTypesOnly` is properly propagated back to the outer (i.e. controller) scope.

Comment: Hi! I would like to try this but what do you mean by initializing `foo` on the outer scope? Where would I have to do that? (sorry I never did anything with AngularJS)

Comment: See the provided example.